# How to indicate one or more match in url pattern?

Tags: java, regex, guice, deployment-descriptor

`"/*"` will match **zero** or more characters. I want to serve request if there is a **one** or more characters
proceeding the "/" character.

Note: I am using Guice's Servlet Module to configure the request.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think "proceeding" is the word you want. Do you mean "following"? "Preceding"? Trying to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do this, assuming you mean that you want to matching anything with a `/` and 1 or more characters after it (so `/foo` and `/a` but not `/`).

```
serveRegex("/.+")
```

Answer (score 0):

in general regex:

```
/+
```

dont know if it works here tough ..?

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletRegexKeyMapping

Comment: This will only match a string of `/` characters.

Comment: well, then you probably have to add an . like mentioned by Colin or (.) like in the link stated (before the +-sign)